# How to use java program to run command prompt commands?

Tags: java, command, command-prompt, ping, prompt

this is my first time posting here, so I'm not really sure what to say/ask.
Anyways, I am trying to make a simple java program that runs command prompt commands from the java program, mainly used for ping flood (ping flooding myself).

Here is my current code

```
public class Core extends JFrame {

JTextField ipTextField;

int packets = 0;

boolean running = false;

public Core() {
    super("Fatique");

    Container container = getContentPane();
    JButton bAttack = new JButton("Start Attack");
    JButton bStop = new JButton("Stop Attack");
    JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();

    container.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    ipTextField = new JTextField("IP Address", 30);
    container.add(ipTextField);

    bAttack.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            String input = ipTextField.getText();
            String[] value = input.split(":");

            int amountOfPackets = Integer.parseInt(value[1]);

            exec("cmd /c" + input + " -t -n " + amountOfPackets);
            running = true;
        }
    });

    bStop.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            stop();
        }
    });

    if(!running) {
        jPanel.add(bAttack);
    } else {
        jPanel.add(bStop);
    }

    add(jPanel);
}  

public void exec(String cmd) {
    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        System.out.println(getOutput(p) + " - " + getPacketsSent());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public String getOutput(Process p) {
    String output = null;

    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            output = line;
            packets++;
        }

        return output;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getStackTrace());
    }

    return null;
}

public int getPacketsSent() {
    return packets;
}

public void stop() {
    exec("cmd /c break");
    running = false;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {  
    Core c = new Core();
    c.setSize(500, 300);
    c.setVisible(true);
    c.setResizable(false);
    c.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    c.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}
```

I'm quite new at java, so that might not do what I want it to do.
What I want it to do is I enter an ip address in the textfield, and split it with ":", and after that the amount of packets, for instance

```
127.0.0.1:100
```

Though now when I try to use that ip and packet amount, it returns "null - 0" (from exec method), and I'm not even sure if it did anything related to ping.

What I am trying to accomplish is as I already said, ping flood myself, and then output whatever I get as response, though I have no idea if this code does anything even related to that, I mostly use logic when coding java.

```
 public String getOutput(Process p) {
    String output = null;

    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            output = line;
            packets++;
        }

        return output;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getStackTrace());
    }

    return null;
}
```

Could someone explain me why my code code is not working how I want it to work? Please don't judge, as I already said, I'm quite new to java programming.

EDIT: Here is a quick "informative" explanation of what I am trying to accomplish.

1. I type in an ip address and how many packets I want to send. In this explanation, I am using localhost ip, and 5 packets.
   [image: About to send 5 packets to localhost ip]
2. I start the attack. At this part, I want the program to run cmd prompt command

   ping 127.0.0.1 -t -n 5

   127.0.0.1 being the ip that I put in the textfield in my program, and 5 is the amount of packets I put in the textfield.
3. I started the attack, so this is what should happen in the command prompt:
   [image: 5 packets sent to locahost]

   The language is Finnish, but still the same thing.

   This is the basic explanation of what I am trying to accomplish, hopefully someone understood and can help/tell why my code is not working, or is working but not printing the proper lines in eclipse console.

Comment: Try printing the raw output of the process' input stream.

Comment: Still null, though I probably didn't do what you told me to do. System.out.println(in.readLine()); That is what I tried, now it returns "null
null - 1"

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

```
try {
       Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
       Process p = rt.exec("ping 192.168.16.67");
       InputStream in = p.getInputStream();
       OutputStream out = p.getOutputStream ();
       InputStream err = p.getErrorStream();
       p.destroy();
} catch(Exception exc) {}
```

Then, you'll have to read the `out` variable to parse the `ping` command output continuously.

Comment: This doesn't help them learn what they did wrong. Note, their question was not 'How do I do this?" but rather "Why is this not working?" As such, this doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: ^ Exactly, thanks. I just noticed that I forgot to put "ping" in the command.. now packets int is going up 1 every time I press the start button, which is not what I was going for. Output is still null.

Answer (score 4):

There is a problem with your getOutput method.  It looks like you intend to collect every line of output.  But in fact, since you are assigning `line` to `output`, you will only return the last line before the end of stream.

To fix this, change

```
    output = line;
```

to

```
    output += line + "\n";
```

Or to be more correct:

```
    output += line + LINE_SEPARATOR;
```

where you previously declared the latter as:

```
    final String LINE_SEPARATOR = System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

---

That doesn't directly explain why you are getting `null`, but that might be because the command you are running is writing output to the 'error' stream rather than the 'output' stream.

Comment: Still returning null. If I just use System.out.println(line), it kind of works, but not how I want it to. What I want it to do is to print the response, for instance, when I type "ping 127.0.0.1 -t -n 1", it's going to reply "Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128", and that is what I want to print each and every time. In my program, if I type "127.0.0.1:5", then it's going to print the response every time, which in this case would be 5, because that's the amount of packets I sent. With my current code, no matter how many packets I send, it prints -->

Comment: "Ping-pyynt”: tuntematon is„nt„ 127.0.0.1:2."

Answer (score 0):

```
bAttack.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String input = ipTextField.getText();
        String[] value = input.split(":");

        int amountOfPackets = Integer.parseInt(value[1]);

        try {
            p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping -n "+amountOfPackets+" "+value[0]);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        running = true;


    }
```

Just a small modification of your code. get output is as:

```
public String getOutput(Process p) {
String output = null;

try {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String line = null;
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        output =output+ line+"\n";
        packets++;
    }

    return output;
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println(e.getStackTrace());
}

return null;
}
```

Here output is JTextArea I have taken to display the output of PING process. I cannot show you the output because I lack reputation.

I don't know why first line is null. Anyway, it works.

Hope this help you. Have good time coding.